# How can pytest find test files without __init__.py in the test folders?

Tags: pytest

According to the [pytest good practices doc](http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractices.html) you should not have `__init__.py` in your test directories.

If I remove the `__init__.py` files, pytest does not find any tests with this command:

`PYTHONPATH=../. py.test -m "slow" --color=yes -svv -f tests` (invoked with `sh tests/run_slow_tests.sh`)

I'm a fairly experienced pytest user, but I still have no idea how to run my tests without `__init__.py`. How do I run my tests without them in my test folders?

Answer (score 0):

Pytest relies on magic naming for tests discovery. Ideally, all your test files have to start with `test_`, e.g., instead of `slow.py` you need to use `test_slow.py`. The test methods also have to start with `test_`, e.g. `def test_a():`, `def test_b():` etc. If all these conditions are met, then simply running `pytest` in a test folder will perform the [test discovery](https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/naming_conventions.html) and run all discovered tests.

If your file *does not* contain the `test_` prefix, then you should pass the file name as an explicit argument, i.e. `pytest slow.py`.

If test methods are inside a class then the class name **`must`** start with `Test` or contain `Test` somewhere in the name. If it does not, then you will have to explicitly specify the class e.g. with:

```
    pytest -s -v slow.py::CreateAndSubmitForm
```

Comment: This is not my problem; I follow all the conventions. But still useful info for a newb :)